# Windows 11 having probems with windows on multiple monitors with different scaling

Tags: windows, display, windows-11, scaling

I've got two fullHD monitors connected to a 4k laptop, with 100% and 300% scaling. My problem is that when I try to pull a window from the 4k monitor to another the window won't scale back to 100% until the window is not fully on the fullHD monitor, but most of the times, the window won't even fit on the screen because it's still 3 times the size of the monitor